Directory Modules not recognized by Library
Libraries are imported as dependencies in main.toml file,however in this case the submodules are not imported as expected.
Existing Modules(output_0.rs/mod_1/output_1.rs) are not recognized as part of library(mods_dir/lib.rs).
error[E0583]: file not found for module `output_0`
  --> mod_dirs\src\lib.rs:18:5
   |
18 |     pub mod output_0;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: to create the module `output_0`, create file "mod_dirs\src\mods_dir\output_0.rs" or "mod_dirs\src\mods_dir\output_0\mod.rs"

EDIT : Reuploaded a clearer image showing main.toml where the mods_dir.lib get imported as a dependency. –


Please do not post images, and describe your problem using text as it is easily copyable and searchable.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Module tree must be in the same layout like your file tree. You are defining module crate::mods_dir::output_0, and yet your src/ directory contains output_0.rs file, and not mods_dir/output_0.rs. See a section of The Book on how to layout modules or The Rust Reference.
You can solve it in two ways:

Fix your file structure/module structure (either put output_0.rs in mods_dir/, or remove mods_dir module). This should be the best solution, as there is a common convention on how Rust projects are laid out, and if you change it, others might find it confusing.

Use #[path] attribute on modules, to override where they point at.


#[path = "."]
mod mods_dir {
    pub mod output_0;
}


mods_dir is a library with nested modules ,crate::mods_dir::output_0 is correct . Libraries are imported as dependencies in main.toml file. Reuploaded a clearer image showing main.toml where the mods_dir.lib get imported as a dependency.

Directories need not be included as modules when they have a .lib file associated with them ,as they are directly recognized by the compiler.
However, they need to be added to the main.toml as a dependency
so that the lib directory's content get associated it and compiled along with the bin file.
In the above case ,the Directory mods_dir was getting reimported into main as it was declared as module mod mods_dir in its own .lib file.Removing mod mods_dir and directly importing its submodules solved the issue.
mods_dir.lib

PREVIOUS:
mod mods_dir {
    pub mod output_0;
}


NOW:
 pub mod output_0;

